# Camera app in sencha + Phone Gap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, android-camera, voice-recording

I am new in sencha, I need to develop an app in Sencha and can have the option of using Phone Gap with it.

It will be an android app. I need to work with Camera and Voice Recorder, Need an option to send image and recorded audio to the server. How can I complete this requirement in Sencha and Phone Gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the tutorial provided by Sencha at :
http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

After completed the tutorial, you have everything to create a Sencha application for  PhoneGap.

PhoneGap expose specific device feature to make it accessible in the JavaScript environment.
It can be properties, events or methods.
So search for your desired features in the PhoneGap documentation (very good documentation) then you'll see what PhoneGap can do for you. Adapt the examples from the documentation to the Sencha notation, then you are done !

Here is some hints :

1. Camera :
   http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html
2. Recording audio:
   http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord
3. File transfert to a server:
   http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Hope it will help you make it through...

Goog luck